# How to unpack specific directory from /home backup packed with pigz+tar+gzip

Tags: backup, tar, gzip

Normally I'm extracting my copies with:

```
pigz -dc backup2_week1_system.tar.gz | tar xzvf -
```

Now I want to unpack specific directory from /home/user for example admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pigz -dc backup2_week1_system.tar.gz | tar vxf - FILE
```

where `FILE` is the file to extract. For example

```
pigz -dc backup2_week1_system.tar.gz | tar vxf - bob
```

Will extract the `bob` directory (e.g. `/home/bob`) from `backup2_week1_system.tar.gz`. Note that you don't need the `z` flag because `pigz` will already decompress the `gzip`'d portion.